# Python - Django 1.5 Is there a possible workaround to fix database error

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, sqlite

Im working a school management project and I integrated a forum app. It now pushes a database error even after I migrated / synced the database. Are there possible workarounds?

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/forums/category/add/
Django Version:     1.5.12
Exception Type:     DatabaseError
Exception Value:

no such column: django_content_type.name

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 362
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.15

Error in Ubuntu terminal below

"Creating tables ...
DatabaseError: no such column: django_content_type.name"

Comment: Sounds like a column is missing

Answer (score 1):

Check your Django version be that version used in project.
Then:

```
     manage.py migrate contenttypes 0001 

     manage.py runserver
```